# Error when exporting the result of a valid command as a bash variable

Tags: bash, command-line, osx, environment-variables, aws

I'm trying to export the result of a command line as en environment variable. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
group_id=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=${group_name} \
  | jq '.["SecurityGroups"][0].GroupId' \
  | sed -e 's/^"//'  -e 's/"$//'
)
```

However when I run the bash file, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--filters': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:

 ^
```

The command is valid, as it works when I try it directly from the command line. When I use `set -exv` on the top of this bash file, I get the content of the file then:

```
+ case $1 in
+ init
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=${group_name} \
++ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=docker-networking ' '

Error parsing parameter '--filters': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:

 ^
+ group_id=
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Can you run your script with `set -xv`?

Comment: @choroba i've updated the question after setting `set -xv`

Comment: Does it work if you put the whole pipe on one line?

Comment: Ah it worked, but what's the problem with the `\\`?

Comment: I have no idea. Is the \ really the last character at the line?

Comment: yeah, you can see it in the command above.

Comment: I can see a `' '` at the end of the line with `++`, which is weird.

Comment: ok so there is a space after `\\` that caused a parsing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a space after the backslash. To make multiline commands, the backslash must be the very last character on a line.

Deduced from the output of `set -xv`:

```
++ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=docker-networking ' '
                                                                              here ->  ~~~
```